# Eclipse Code review for android

Tags: java, android, eclipse-plugin

I have installed plug-ins, checkstyle and PMD, its working fine for the sample project, "/SampleTestProject/src/TestPackage/TestClass.java" , But same plug-ins not at all showing any errors , not highlighting for project " /SampleProject/SampleDemo/Sample_src/SampleTest/src/com/Company/BusinessLogic/BusinessLogic.java"

is it because of folders loop ? Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: what  you have tried So far . its unclear

Comment: I have created a sample project , path looks like this:
"/SampleTestProject/src/TestPackage/TestClass.java",  here I can see warnings in "problems" window.

Same file " TestClass.java", I copied and pasted in another project , path is : "Test1/Test_loop/TestProject/SampleTestProject/src/TestPackage/TestClass.java"
here it will not show errors /warnings also. 

(I just created folders loop and put this project)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,In eclipse right click the project ->checkstyle->activate checkstyle

Comment: checkstyle activation also doesnt make any sense.